nginx configuration is deemed incomplete yet identical to other installation
requesting an application page, the response is:
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
However, no logging is occuring in either the /var/log/nginx/access.log nor /var/log/nginx/error.log
the site-enabled configuration file has the following:
server {
  server_name sart.2ld.ws

  root /home/deploy/mrkt/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;

  location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name mrkt_websocket;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }

  # Allow uploads up to 100MB in size
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  location ~ ^/(assets|packs) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }

  location ~ /(wp|wp-content|solr|jsonws|mifs|wp-includes|login.asp)/ {
      return 404;
  }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sart.2ld.ws/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sart.2ld.ws/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = sart.2ld.ws) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

  server_name sart.2ld.ws
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

It is identical to that on another server which is responding as expected.
Note: passenger is also installed.
What further configuration might be needed?

Isn't there a symlink to sites available you have to create? Check your nginx.conf

Yes, nginx.conf includes [ahem] include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;         include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; in fact other applications on same server are rendering as expected.

Can you test with nginx -T and grep if the config for sart.2ld.ws is loaded?

yes, the -T output has the full configuration for # configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mrkt:   However I am intrigued by the fact that this configuration file contents precedes the content of # configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf: then continues with other configuration files.  Does the sequence have meaning?

afaik the sequence matters in the nginx configuration

the sequence appears to be moot.  three applications, 1 is before, 2 are after the options-ssl-nginx.conf file.  All are responding to requests.

Are you sure there is no other server block acting as a default server? It can also be checked used the already suggested nginx -T command. Check the "How nginx processes a request" article for the additional details.

the eyes are on strike type of error:
server_name sart.2ld.ws;

was lacking a semi-colon in the question.
